# Confused about Positive Definiteness and Invertibility.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Consider the objective of solving the generalized unconstrained quadratic optimization problem:
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}\;\;\;\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^{\top}Qx}+\mathbf{q^{\top}x}
$$
We know that by computive the gradient and setting it to the zero vector, we obtain:
$$
\mathbf{Qx+q}=\mathbf{0}
$$
My professor makes the following assumption:

> If $\mathbf{Q}$ is full-rank and "Postive Semi-Definite (PSD)", then $\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{Q^{-1}q}$

Question:

> Why do we need $\mathbf{Q}$ to be both full-rank and PSD if we know that any matrix being full rank should already imply that its also positive definite PD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think $\boldsymbol{Q}$ being full rank implies it being Positive Definite. In fact, consider
$$ A = \left[\begin{matrix}2 &4 \\
4 &6 \end{matrix}\right]$$
this has rank 2 (full rank), but if you check the eigenvalues
$$ \lambda_{1} \approx -0.47 < 0; \quad \lambda_{2} \approx 8.47 > 0,$$
the first one is negative, therefore the matrix is not Positive Definite.

The full rank requirement is necessary for $\boldsymbol{Q}$ to be invertible, whereas its Positive Semi-Definiteness is necessary to ensure that the function
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^{\top}Qx}+\mathbf{q^{\top}x}
$$
is convex, and therefore the minimum you are looking for exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification, this pretty much answers my question.